# Is there a "Hilbert syzygy theorem" for smooth manifolds?  Or: does every finitely generated $C^\infty$ module have a finite-length resolution in vector bundles?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a real smooth manifold, and $M$ a locally-finitely-generated sheaf of $\mathcal C^\infty(X)$-modules.  (If $X$ is not compact, I will also insist that there be a global bound on the number of generators I might need in different regions; maybe this is part of the usual meaning of the words "locally finitely generated".)

I would like to find finite-dimensional vector bundles $E_1,\dots,E_n$ over $X$ and maps of $\mathcal C^\infty$-modules
$$ 0 \to \Gamma(E_n) \to \dots \to \Gamma(E_1) \to M \to 0$$
so that the sequence is exact.  Can I always do this?  And is there an explicit bound on the number of vector bundles needed, e.g. $n = \dim X$ or $n = \dim X+1$?

Comment: Since your ring is non-Noetherian, you might have to build in a coherency condition or at least require that the module be of finite presentation. Or you could allow for projective modules of infinite rank. If your interests are cohomological, it is true that on a smooth compact manifold sheaf cohomology of, I think, any sheaf of abelian groups vanishes above the dimension n. The reference is "Sheaves on Manifolds". 

Comment: Finite presentation does not suffice, it seems.

Comment: There is a stronger condition, the existence of a (possibly infinite) resolution of f.g. projectives. I doubt that even that would be sufficient however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be $\mathbb R$. In the ring $C^{\infty}(X)$ let $I$ be the ideal of all functions vanishing to infinite order at $0$. The module $C^{\infty}(X)/I$ does not have a finite resolution by finitely generated projective modules.

Edit:

Still no if you want the finitely generated module to be contained in a finitely generated projective module. For the same $X$ pick a function $f$ such $f(x)$ vanishes precisely when $x<0$. let $J$ be the ideal generated by $f$. The module $J$ does not have a finite resolution by finitely generated projective modules.

For both of these examples, the method I have in mind is this: If a module $M$ has a finite projective resolution $P_\bullet$ then for every point in $p\in X$ the alternating sum of the $k_p$ vector space dimension of $Tor_n(M,k_p)$ is independent of $p$ because it's the alternating sum of the rank of $P_n$. I believe that in the first example this Euler number comes out to be $1$ if $p$ is the origin and otherwise $0$, and in the second it's $1$ if $p> 0$ and $0$ if $p< 0$.

Comment: Awesome.  Do you know if the answer is "yes" if I insist that $M$ be a submodule of (the sheaf of sections of) some vector bundle?  Or I can ask that as another MO question...

Comment: The answer is still "no". I'll explain in an edit.

Comment: Doesn't the example given in the edit essentially show that $C^\infty(X)$ is not coherent as a sheaf of rings?  I've heard it said that Serre gave this counterexample when developing the theory of coherent sheaves, but can't find it in FAC.  Anyway, this kind of property -- the structure sheaf not being coherent -- seems to rule out translating a lot of the sheafy power of tools from analytic or algebraic geometry over to differential topology.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good way to summarize the situation. 